# how to access properties in .then function using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is my code

```
  methods: {
    async pay() {
      this.$notify(`working`);
      if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
        try {
          var data = {
            to: this.to,
            subject: this.subject,
          };

          let response = await axios
            .post("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs", data)
            .then(() => {
              this.$notify(`email has been sent`);
            
            })
            .catch(error => {
              const message = error.response.data.message;
              this.$notify("Oh oo!", `${message}`, "error");
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

i'm trying to display

```
 this.$notify(`email has been sent`);
```

immediately the email has been sent but it doesn't work it even if i put in console.log or alert the function in the .then doesn't go through

i get working from

```
  this.$notify(`working`);
```

immediately i fire the function , please how can i go about this

Comment: As a guiding rule, if you're writing `async/await` code and you find yourself really wanting to type `.then()`, stop and re-think what you're doing.

Comment: Besides the previous comment, it's done the way you did it. It's not specific to $notify and you shouldn't rely on it for debugging, consider using proper ways. If neither then and catch callbacks are triggered this means that the promise is pending, in this case that the request is stalled, you can debug it on your side in devtools. If the problem persists, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be your backend i had the same issue try adding

```
 res.json({
            status: true,
            message: "save succes",
           });
```